# Cleaner way to choose LifetimeScope in a dependency chain with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm using a web app with Autofac injecting services into controllers. Those services are sometimes injected with other services, and repositories. Repositories are injected with DbContexts. These 3 layers (service, repository, context) are all registered with Autofac. My default lifetime for these is InstancePerLifetimeScope.

Unfortunately, I have some code in a specific controller that I want to execute in parallel threads. Since DbContext is not thread-safe, this means I need to give a factory method to each thread to resolve a Service in a per dependency lifetime scope, which in turn will need to resolve per dependency repositories and db contexts.

The options I am considering are to create a new lifetime scope per thread, or to use a separate registration using a named or keyed registration to resolve the per-dependency services.

The challenge with creating a new lifetime scope per thread is that I need access to some per-scope objects. Some objects would need to be inherited and to not have a new instance created in the new scope, but other objects (the non-thread-safe DbContexts) need to have new instances generated in the new scope. I have no idea how to control this behavior implicitly when creating my new lifetime scope.

The other method would be to use a registration key so that when I execute the factory method to resolve a service on each thread, it would resolve one in the per-dependency scope. This would work if the service had no dependencies, but since it depends on a bunch of repositories or services for which the default lifetime scope is set to InstancePerLifetimeScope, I have to write something like this:

```
    builder.RegisterType<MyService>()
        .As<IMyService>()
        .Named<IMyService>(RegistrationKeys.PerDependency)
            .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IMyRepository),
            (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<IMyRepository>(RegistrationKeys.PerDependency))
        ).InstancePerDependency();
```

Since the repositories depend on the DbContext, each repository has to be registered separately using this registration name. And it needs to be configured to resolve the DbContext using the registration name. And the DbContext needs to be registered using the registration name.

With 10 services each using about 4-5 repositories, I wager the amount of boilerplate registration code I will have to write will be around 10-20 full pages. It's not going to be maintainable.

So my question is, is there a way to create a specific type of lifetime scope that will allow me to easily control which objects will have a new instance or which will be inherited from the parent lifetime scope that won't break the asp.net per-request lifetime scope?

Or is there a way I can register or resolve a service to explicitly resolve all of its dependencies *in the same scope* without relying on their default registrations and without having to hard code an entire second set of registrations for everything?

Comment: Have you tried InstancePerRequest?

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-request

Comment: I am using InstancePerRequest essentially. When using Autofac with ASP.NET Core, you use InstancePerLifetimeScope instead of InstancePerRequest. It's essentially the same thing.

Comment: Well, I don't know. I had similar situation with DbContext and InstancePerLifetimeScope and wasn't able to make it work. So I had to move to InstancePerDependency. Couldn't find any issue so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The challenge with creating a new lifetime scope per thread is that I need access to some per-scope objects. Some objects would need to be inherited and to not have a new instance created in the new scope, but other objects (the non-thread-safe DbContexts) need to have new instances generated in the new scope. I have no idea how to control this behavior implicitly when creating my new lifetime scope.

This is the challenge `InstancePerRequest` solve. You can create child scope and object scoped to `Request` will be shared amongst child scope. To do this, tagged lifetimescope and `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope` is used.

You can see [`InstancePerRequest`](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html) and [Tagging a lifetime scope](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#tagging-a-lifetime-scope) in the official documentation.

Example :

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("KEY");
builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// ...

using (ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("KEY"))
{
    scope.Resolve<IService>(); // Instance #1

    using (ILifetimeScope childScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        childScope.Resolve<DbContext>();
        childScope.Resolve<IService>(); // shared instance (#1)
    }
}
```

but that's mean you have to change all your `InstancePerLifetimeScope` to `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope` and can control the creation of the *unit of work* lifetime scope which can be quite difficult.

Another way of doing this is by using `Owned<T>` with `Func<T>`. You can get more information here : [Owned instance](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html)

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<Operation>().As<IOperation>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();


public class Operation : IOperation 
{
    public Operation(Func<Owned<DbContext>> contextFactory, IService service)
    {
        this._contextFactory = contextFactory;
        this._service = service; 
    }
    private readonly Func<Owned<DbContext>> _contextFactory;
    private readonly IService _service;

    public void Do() 
    {
        using Owned<DbContext> context = this._contextFactory(); 

        context.Value // => new instance 
        this._service // shared instance (#1) 

    }
}

using (ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    scope.Resolve<IService>(); // Instance #1

    IEnumerable<IOperation> operations = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IOperation>>();
    operations.AsParallel()
              .ForAll(operation => operation.Do());
}
```

The only downside of this solution is that your service will have dependency on *Autofac* but if you don't want it, it is quite easy to create your own abstraction over `Owned`

If you don't want to use `Owned<T>` or your own abstraction instead of trying to make `DbContext` a special case you can reverse the problem and manually share some dependency between your custom scope.

Something like :

```
using ILifetimeScope childScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope(b => {
    b.Register<XContext>(c => scope.Resolve<XContext>()).ExternallyOwned(); 
});

var operation = childScope.Resolve<IOperation>();
operation.Do();
```

This way `IOperation` would be resolved in a new scope but `XContext` will be from parent scope

Comment: It would seem that when using Autofac with ASP.NET Core, there is no tag on the LifetimeScope of a request.

Comment: I have yet to find a workaround for this in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: No tag on the request scope is an artifact of ASP.NET Core in general, not specifically Autofac. [The differences between classic ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core are documented](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#differences-from-asp-net-classic) and that's one of them.

Comment: `InstancePerLifetimeScope` and `Owned<T>` is probably the easiest way to go, but you can always create _your own_ lifetime scopes inside the controller to handle isolation of threads/units of work, too.

Comment: @TrevorElliott could you explain why you need to share the same instance against the "per request" scope and the "thread" scope ? is it to share any kind of context ? You can look at my edit how you can reverse the problem and share context information

Comment: As it is a multi-tenant application, there are middlewares which run that load user information from the DB into context objects. These objects are DI dependencies of the DbContexts.

Comment: In the end, I decided not to go with this approach. The multi-threading was only present within a single request in my API, which was more of an indicator that it was poorly written and needed to be optimized to avoid the number of database calls it was making.

Since each request is already on its own thread and the app is potentially handling hundreds or more requests at any time, I don't think a single request should be hogging that many threads.